# getting started with weblogic portal 11g

Tags: weblogic11g

I'm a Vietnamese Developer, and have just getting started with weblogic portal 11g. So, i hope you give me some guide:
I install weblogic portal on my machine, and create a domain. When i started this domain by /startWeblogc, i see a only Admin Console site at localhost:7001/console but not a basic portal site (like MS sharepoint..). Do you thing i miss something or it is the way of weblogic: if i want a portal,  i must create one from scratch.
Thanks very much,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you see only the OOTB admin console.

You have to actually develop your portal using Weblogic Workshop

See the docs for more

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13218_01/wlp/docs100/portals/wizards_and_setup.html#wp1014123